# Navigationbar title and back button name are same?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created one title for navigationbar in my storyboard project ,but when I moved to next viewcontroller the back button shows the same name as my previous navigationbar(Main navigationbar) title.? Can i set separate title and back button names?

I tried following code but its not working ? why?

```
 self.navigationItem.title=@"Recent Books";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"Back";
```

Comment: That answer not working for me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [UINavigationItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem)

> "When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the
>   stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the
>   navigation bar from this navigation item. [...] If you want to specify
>   a custom image or title for the back button, you can assign a custom
>   bar button item (with your custom title or image) to this property
>   instead."

So try this in your first VC from where you are pushing other VC

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Recent Books";
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:nil
                                   action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=backButton;
```

Comment: I have two BarButton customized on my first view, on the left to "Information" and the right to "Settings". And yet, I had to set a name for BackButton in the first view to. In my component tree now are three BarButton, but when I run the app everything worked normally. Simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you are pushing your viewcontroller A -> B

In viewcontroller A try adding this code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn_Back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=btn_Back;
```

So you will see your "Back" button in viewcontroller B

Answer (score 2):

The following should solve your problem

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"back";
}
```

You can also use this Objective-C syntax

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar backItem] setTitle:@"back"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in this way , one of the easiest way I did find till now :

**Create a custom back button and add it into the Navigation Bar left button item property :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Backnavigation.png"]  ; // Here set the back button image
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}


//Handle the Back Button Event
- (void) handleBack:(id)sender
{
    // do your custom handler code here
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also, doing this way, you don't need to change the title of NavigationBar every-time.

*Here is the Back Button for your reference :*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in the **viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)** method of the view controller in which you want to set the backButton title of you choice :
    `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back Title", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)`